# Adjectives order (old-fashioned)

Tags: adjective-order

I have to put the **adjectives** in the **correct order** to complete the sentences.

They only had _____ _____ (**leather**, **old-fashioned**) gloves in the sale, so I'll have to keep looking for those.

Adjective order:
Opinion, Size/Age, Colour/Pattern, **Material**, Make/Type, Noun 
In this sentence **leather is material** but what is **old-fashioned** - type or opinion? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instinctively, "*Old-fashioned leather gloves*" sounds correct to me as a native BrEng speaker. And I would agree that "old-fashioned" is an *opinion* rather than a "type", because they certainly were not "old-fashioned" when they were made so that cannot really describe the *style*. It is a matter of opinion that they are no longer in-style and therefore old-fashioned.